# Convert string into a mathematical set operation in Python

Tags: python, math, set, operators

I have a set equation from user input, that can look like `'A&B|C'` where `A, B` and `C` are some finite sets from the set of natural numbers. What I want to do is change the input from type string into an actual set operation which after execution would yield a proper result.

E.g. if `A={4,5} B={5,6}` I want the string input `'A&B'` to return `{5}`

Any ideas how can I do this? Thank you

**Edit:**
I was able to evaluate the expression by the eval() method. However, this only works if the sets are predefined, as suggested:

```
>>> A={4,5}
>>> B={5,6}
>>> eval('A&B')
```

However, what can I do if I haven't predefined `A` and `B`, since I don't know the user input beforehand. When I do:

```
my_input = input("Type equation: ")
print(eval(my_input))
```

After input `A&B` , I get `error name 'A' not defined` . I tried copying the characters into a list and then transforming each element into `set()` but that hasn't worked either. Any suggestions?

Comment: How/where is the input for `A` and `B` taken from the user? You input just `A&B` in your second example, but in order to get `{5}`, you still need to specify what `A` and `B` actually are at some point.

Comment: I use this equation for Venn diagram highlighting, such that the user does not actually define the content of the set, but only inputs the equation `A&B`, and the middle part of the Venn diagram would be highlighted. So I guess the best approach is to assign A and B some arbitrary numbers but is it possible?

Comment: that's why I tried copying the input, creating a list of only character values `"A&B" => ['A','B']` and then loop through the list and assign each element an arbitrary set. But that hasn't worked either

Comment: Not sure what's the scope you're trying to cover. But maybe take a look at Sympy (https://sympy.org).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the eval() function:

```
>>> A={4,5}
>>> B={5,6}
>>> eval('A&B')
{5}
```

Comment: hey Ethan, can you please check my edit and see whether there is any workaround?

Comment: @SamuelV. I’m not clear on what you are trying to achieve. If A and B have not been defined then there is nothing to evaluate. You can store the user passed equation as a string and then use eval() on said stored string to return the results after A and B are defined.

Comment: no worries, it is kinda hard for me to explain but I see what you mean, My code  now it looks like - to initialize the sets:         
    `A = set()
    B = set()
    C = set()
    D = set()
    E = set()`                                                                                                                        
I use this to initialize the sets,but the issue is what if I want to continue up to Z, or even have different names than just
I tried doing:
    `arr = [A,B,C,D,E]
    for element in arr: element = set()`

Comment: but this hasn't worked, how else can I  initialize the sets, without doing it on every line separately

Comment: @SamuelV. Maybe a broader context of what your application is trying to achieve. Is it for teaching the mathematical concepts of sets(that’s the impression I get). If so a few well thought out sets that can demonstrate the various operations should be very effective.